# How do I create .desktop file for repository program?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, .desktop, installed-programs

After installing an icon theme I realize some of my application icons have not changed. Upon looking there are multiple application missing from `/usr/share/applications`. I have install all my programs from ***repository*** so I don't know how to make a .desktop file for them. The missing programs Are (Chromium, WPS office, Bitwarden, simple screen recorder, GNOME Chess). All the programs  runs well but icon theme don't work on them. Help please.

Comment: If you hit the `Super` key (the Windows key) and search for one of the "missing" programs, does it show an icon there?

Comment: Yes. it is solved now from the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have installed the [snap version](https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started) of those applications mentioned in the question. You should find the associated `.desktop` files in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. But it is not recommended to directly edit these files. Instead copy a `.desktop` file to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory first and then edit the copied file.